# Why hyphenate no one: no-one?

Tags: hyphenation

Came across this article today:

[New York shooting: Gunfire at Irving Plaza leaves one person dead](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-36385984)

which had the following sentence:

> No-one has been arrested and the motive for the shooting is unclear.

screengrab:

[image]

I've never seen no one hyphenated like this before. I even had to read it twice just to get it.

Why hyphenate no one: no-one?

Comment: I think you have to ask the editor of the article. It is a typo. But will "no-one" cause any confusion?

Comment: The article said rapper TI was supposed to perform, so when I got to "no-one" I, wrongly, assumed it was another rapper!

Comment: No-one blinded Polyphemus!

Comment: The standard progression for this type of thing is first two words, then hyphenated, then one word. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+morrow%2Cto-morrow%2Ctomorrow&year_start=1650&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20morrow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20-%20morrow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctomorrow%3B%2Cc0).  While the one-word *no one* is a problem because *noone* looks like *noon* and *noöne* has an almost-obsolete diaeresis, the hyphenated *no-one* is perfectly fine, and could easily be standard in the late 21st century.

Answer (score 7):

It's not a typo, it's a deliberate decision to use a hyphen.  "no-one" is sometimes used with a hyphen - some people believe that this avoids confusion with the other usage of "no one" meaning "no single", as in

*"No one man should have this much power."*

So, really it's a matter of preference.  *"no one"* is more *formally* correct, but since there's a valid argument to use *"no-one"* when you mean *"nobody"* and *"no one"* when you mean *"no single"* (as detailed above), then I don't think you could say that *"no-one"* is definitely *wrong*.  Language evolves and changes all the time, depending on people's needs.

Comment: Hi, Max. I generally agree with you. But wouldn't it better to write "Not one man / Not a single man / No man should have this much power"? I am curious. What is your thought?

Comment: I'd say they're all options, and it's up to the writer which one they use.

Comment: Agreed, @MaxWilliams.  I prefer it with hyphen because it's pronounced [in terms of stress and tone] as if it's a single word.

Comment: @DavidGarner good point, there's less of a gap between the words isn't there, with no-one versus "no one man", although that might be because people, when saying "no one man" are aware of the potential for confusion and so deliberately leave more of a gap to mitigate it.

Comment: When I subbed for a well-known news agency, the style guide stipulated that we use a hyphen. It was to reduce ambiguity, as mentioned above. That proves nothing other than that the person who wrote the guide made that decision.

Answer (score 0):

"No-one" is incorrect. "No one" is two words. I wouldn't call it a typo, so much as an incorrect spelling.
Originally, it was one word, spelt "noöne", and many other English words, such as "coöperate" and "reälity" were also spelt with a diaeresis (an exclusively English diacritic, and not the same thing as the German umlaut) to indicate that both vowels were pronounced separately, rather than being a diphthong.
It's not often seen today, outside of "naïve" and "Noël", and the names "Zoë" and "Chloë", although it seems *The New Yorker* is making an move to bring it back.

Comment: The notion that the original form of *any* English word formed from two others is written with a diaresis is suspect, but the OED listing is *no one*, with the note *The hyphenated form no-one seems to have been introduced in the mid 19th cent. and to have remained uncommon until the late 20th cent. It remains a minority variant.* The [BBC prefers it](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/flatmates/episode71/languagepoint.shtml), which gives us the real answer: it is a matter of style, and the hyphen observes [BBC style](http://www.bbc.co.uk/academy/journalism/news-style-guide).

Comment: I would venture to say BBC is wrong…